# How to prevent row deselection on right click

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I have a grid with a context menu. I know how to prevent row selection on right click. I just do it in this way:

```
var allowSelection=true;
Ext.getCmp('grid').on('beforeitemmousedown', function(grid, record, item, index, event, eOpts) { 
if (event.button==0) allowSelection=true ;
else allowSelection=false;
});
Ext.getCmp('grid').on('beforeselect', function(grid, record, index, eOpts) { 
 return allowSelection;
});
```

But what I now need is to prevent row deselection. In fact, even though the current code prevents row selection, it does not prevent row deselection.

**EDIT**

My right click event causes a context menu to pop up. The part of code, which does it, is this one

```
listeners:{
    itemcontextmenu:function(view,record,item,index,e){
      e.stopEvent();
      gridMenu.showAt(e.getXY());
    },
    containercontextmenu:function(view, e){
      e.stopEvent();
      gridMenu.showAt(e.getXY());
    }
...
```

This code is nested inside viewconfig of the grid. So, I just do not want to trigger row deselection, when my context menu pops up.

**EDIT**

Well, I did it myself. A just added `return false`:

```
if (event.button==0) allowSelection=true ;
else {
  allowSelection=false;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: You should give your own answer as an real answer, not an edit.

Comment: the answer you provided was working and has extra checks for the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works

```
if (event.button==0) allowSelection=true ;
else {
  allowSelection=false;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: your solution did not work. It uses the wrong events in 4.2.2. Also you do not need to check the button if you use the itemcontextmenu event and item click event.. right and left click events.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by using a variable that is a boolean as a flag, and some action listeners on your grid. Make sure to set the flag to true by default or you will not be able to select anything initially.

```js
allowDeselect: true,
```

Next add listeners to the three actions on your grid, beforeitemclick, beforeitemcontextmenu, beforedeselect.

```js
this.control({
  'yourGridPanelsXtype': {
    beforeitemclick: this.onBeforeItemClickTheXtype,
    beforeitemcontextmenu: this.onBeforeItemContextMenuTheXtype,
    beforedeselect: this.onBeforeDeselectTheXtype,
  }
});
```

and the listeners

```js
/**
 * this action listener sets allow deselect for all left clicks. The context
 * menu.. right click, blocks this event. This means its safe to assume that
 * it always gets fired on only left clicks.
 */
onBeforeItemClickSchedulerList: function() {
    this.allowDeselect = true;
},

/**
 * action listener that gets triggered before we display the context menu.
 * This function checks to see if the record we triggered the event on is
 * selected or not. if it is selected block deselecting records, or if it's
 * not selected, allow selection of the new record. Mimics OS behavior. We
 * assume that this event is always triggered with a right click.
 * @param view is the view that fired the event; the grid
 * @param record is the record that triggered the event
 */
onBeforeItemContextMenuSchedulerList: function(view, record) {
  var grid = this.getReferenceToYourGridFromRefs(),
      sm = grid.getSelectionModel(),
      selected = selectionModel.isSelected(record);

  this.allowDeselect = !selected;
},

/**
 * action listener for before the grid deselects something. This listener
 * checks the allowDeselect variable to see if we are blocking deselects or
 * not.
 * @return a boolean of weather to allow deselection or not.
 */
onBeforeDeselectSchedulerList: function() {
  if (!this.allowDeselect) {
    return false;
  }
},
```

This will allow deselecting when you right click on a record that is not currently selected. Right click on records that are selected will block deselecting.